# Vuetify Template of Creativ Tim does not work well

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

---

I have a problem with a Vuetifiy Template of Creativ Tim Team.

> Template:
>   https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vuetify-material-dashboard#

Problem: The tamplates is based in VueJs and use Vuetify. It already uses many components from Vuetify framework, but if i add a component like ***< v-row>< /v-row>*** or many others, this throws an error like that:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-row> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <VContent>
         <CoreView> at src/components/core/View.vue
           <VApp>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

But the template has already many components from vuetify and these works fine.

Example:

```html
<template>
    <v-container fill-height fluid grid-list-xl>
        <v-layout justify-center wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 md8>
                <material-card color="green" title="Edit Profile" text="Complete your profile">
                    <v-form>
                        <v-container py-0>
                            <v-layout wrap>
                                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                                    <v-text-field label="Company (disabled)" disabled />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                                    <v-text-field class="purple-input" label="User Name" />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                                    <v-text-field label="Email Address" class="purple-input" />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md6>
                                    <v-text-field label="First Name" class="purple-input" />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md6>
                                    <v-text-field label="Last Name" class="purple-input" />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md12>
                                    <v-text-field label="Adress" class="purple-input" />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                                    <v-text-field label="City" class="purple-input" />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                                    <v-text-field label="Country" class="purple-input" />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                                    <v-text-field
                                        class="purple-input"
                                        label="Postal Code"
                                        type="number"
                                    />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12>
                                    <v-textarea
                                        class="purple-input"
                                        label="About Me"
                                        value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
                                    />
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12 text-xs-right>
                                    <v-btn
                                        class="mx-0 font-weight-light"
                                        color="success"
                                    >Update Profile</v-btn>
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-form>
                </material-card>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 md4>
                <material-card class="v-card-profile">
                    <v-avatar slot="offset" class="mx-auto d-block" size="130">
                        <img
                            src="https://demos.creative-tim.com/vue-material-dashboard/img/marc.aba54d65.jpg"
                        />
                    </v-avatar>
                    <v-card-text class="text-xs-center">
                        <h6 class="category text-gray font-weight-thin mb-3">CEO / CO-FOUNDER</h6>
                        <h4 class="card-title font-weight-light">Alec Thompson</h4>
                        <p
                            class="card-description font-weight-light"
                        >Don't be scared of the truth because we need to restart the human foundation in truth And I love you like Kanye loves Kanye I love Rick Owens’ bed design but the back is...</p>
                        <v-btn color="success" round class="font-weight-light">Follow</v-btn>
                    </v-card-text>
                </material-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    //
};
</script>
```

This is a view where there are use and don't throw any error

> Any suggestions?

Comment: I did not see the `<v-row>` component being used in the example you have provided. Maybe you need to have the component registered (or used) by your component.

Comment: It's because it uses an older version of Vuetify

Comment: @Angelo The <v-row> was a component example. If i put there that don't work.

Comment: @Zim how i can update vuetify? The actual version in the project is  "vuetify": "1.4.3"

Comment: Ask Creative Tim support